# deployment android project including a remote_service_project as lib

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play, publish, remote-server

Can we publish in play store an android project including a remote_service_project (witch is not published in play store) as lib in deployment?

Comment: AndroiD. Probably, you need an API server wich your app will use?

Comment: if i want to publich in play store an application including a service_project as a librairie , should I publish the service_project in play store or no ?

Comment: Service_project is just background service. Sure, it could be bundled within the main app' apk.